# How can I print line side by side in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, printing, system.out

I couldn't find this anywhere; I might finding it with the wrong keywords.

Pictures paint a thousand words, so let me explain.

Supposed we have a set of unknown number of String:

```
String hello = "Hello world\n Welcome\n"
String goodbye = "Goodbye\n See you in the next life\n"
String do = "Do something\n Be part of us\n"
```

I would like a function that produce such result:

```
String hellogoodbyedo = "
  Hello world_________________Goodbye________________________Do Something\n
  Welcome_____________________See you in the next life_______Be part of us\n"
```

In which *_* means spaces. Is there a smart way of doing such?

Comment: You want to add spaces or the lines, question titled as line side by side but description is about spaces, . . ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
System.out.printf("%-20s%-s20s%-20s%n", field1, field2, field3);
```

Comment: @AdamLiss True, but printf does. ;)

Comment: Yes.  Much better after the edit, and amazing it was upvoted while it was still incorrect.  The perils of crowd-sourcing, I suppose, and probably why government survives.  :-)

Comment: format string has typos. Try: `System.out.printf("%-20s%-20s%-20s", field1, field2, field3);`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Perhaps you should.  The format string is _still_ wrong!

Comment: Thanks, ppl! Now then I knew exactly where to look on Google... lol

Comment: Thanks so much to you and everyone else. What a terrific resource!

Answer (score 4):

Try using tab `\t` or counting the number of char in each line and using a loop to generate spaces between each word.

**edit** split each variable with \n then for each var append the first instance and so on.

Answer (score 4):

There are two parts to the solution.

You can use [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)  to split each string on the newline characters and store the pieces in an array.

Then use `printf` or `String.format()` with a format string as shown in the other answers to left-justify each string:

```
String output = String.format("%-25s%-25s%-25s\n", string1, string2, string3);
```

Answer (score 3):

### Assumptions

- Input is a number of strings
- Each string input contains an unknown number of lines
- Output should be one column per string in the input, conserving line endings
- Output columns shuold be variable width matching the length of input lines

### Method

```
public static String printColumns(String[] input) {
  String result = "";

    // Split input strings into columns and rows
    String[][] columns = new String[input.length][];
    int maxLines = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        columns[i] = input[i].split("\n");
        if (columns[i].length > maxLines)
            maxLines = columns[i].length;
    }

    // Store an array of column widths
    int[] widths = new int[input.length];
    // calculate column widths
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        int maxWidth = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < columns[i].length; j++)
            if (columns[i][j].length() > maxWidth)
                maxWidth = columns[i][j].length();
        widths[i] = maxWidth + 1;
    }

    // "Print" all lines
    for (int line = 0; line < maxLines; line++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < columns.length; column++) {
            String s = line < columns[column].length ? columns[column][line] : "";
            result += String.format("%-"+widths[column]+"s", s);
        }
        result += "\n";
    }
    return result;
}
```

### Usage

```
String hello = "Hello world\nWelcome\n";
String goodbye = "Goodbye\nSee you in the next life\n";
String dosomething = "Do something\nBe part of us\n";
String[] input = {hello, goodbye, dosomething};
System.out.println(printColumns(input));
```

Answer (score 2):

checkout out `printf()` [here](http://www.braju.com/docs/IntroductionToPrintf/)